# W3c Validation gives an error when using data attribute "Attribute data not allowed on element a at this point"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm validating my site using W3C validation and the validation gives error like data attribute is not allowed on anchor tag. I've removed and added the same data attribute to the parent tag again I'm getting the same error for that parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see a reference to a "data attribute", it does not literally mean an attribute called `data`.

A data attribute, more fully known as a *custom data attribute*, is an attribute, of any name and value *you* choose, whose name is prefixed with `data-`. For example, `data-color` or `data-category`. Sometimes they're written as ["`data-*` attributes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-%2a) to make it clearer that the `data-` portion is a prefix and not the entire attribute name.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I just noticed the code had "data" instead of "data-".

Comment: You're welcome, but I had to edit your comment - there is a reason I don't go by my real name on Stack Overflow even though I do elsewhere, so please don't. The way we say thanks on SO is to mark answers as accepted by clicking the checkmark underneath the number.